# how do I insert text between specific lines?

Tags: json, autoit

I am working with AutoIT to add a new entry to a text file. However I need to add it between the last line and second last line.

```
var informationtechnologydivisionmanager = [
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/6/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/13/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/20/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    }   
];
```

When they save new data, I want to be able to insert it after the **}** and before the **];**

I am extremely new to AutoIT and am trying my best to learn it.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's not obvious what AutoIT is, what you are trying to do (except edit some text, which you can do in notepad) and what the success criteria here would be.

Comment: Thanks. Notepad is great and I'm trying to use AutoIT to insert the text.

Comment: I know what AutoIT is but you've not even attempted anything on your own to even give a clue where your starting point is. What's this JSON data or something? What functions are you trying to use to do whatever you need to do with this "data"? Please provide an example of the expected results or something as it's not clear to me what you are trying to do... You may also want to do some reading on the topic and try to get an idea of a function or something so clarify what you're trying to do as stating `When they save new data, I want to be able to insert it after the } and before the ];`??

Comment: Who are "they" and what are they saving data in and with exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exactly to add new data between the **last line** and **second last line** you can use this code:

```
$aFile = FileReadToArray("text.txt")

$fNew = FileOpen("text.txt",2)
$StringCount = UBound($aFile)-1
$StringToInsert = $StringCount-1  ; number of string from end to insert

for $i=0 to $StringCount
    FileWriteLine($fNew, $aFile[$i])
    if $i = $StringToInsert then FileWriteLine($fNew, "########New Data Here!###########")
Next

FileClose($fNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should start you in the right direction:

```
$FileToLoad = "File_Name" ;your file name with the ext
$String = FileRead($FileToLoad)
msgbox(0,"File Content", $String)
$Newinfo = "This is new information"
msgbox(0, "New File Content", StringTrimRight($String, 2) & $Newinfo & @CRLF & "];")
```